# Выплывший или выплывшего?

Tags: причастия, окончания

Как правильно будет написать: серп месяца, выплывшИЙ из-за туч/ серп месяца, выплывшЕГО из-за туч? К какому слову относится причастие?

Comment: Вы-то как думаете? Вам, наверное, и вся фраза известна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так оба варианта хороши. Зависит от рассказчика.

Если он реагирует именно на серп (красота какая!), то согласование будет с серпом.

Если неважно, какие именно очертания (фазу) имеет месяц, то с месяцем.

Answer (score 1):

Разное согласование действительно возможно, как уже было сказано в первом ответе, также при выборе варианта учитывается **контекст.** Я же добавлю пояснения **по грамматике.**

В самом сочетании **"серп месяца"** уже отражено внимание наблюдателя к форме месяца: слово "месяц" (Р.п.) определяет главное слово "серп" (И.п.). И именно серп будет являться **подлежащим** в  предложении.

Что происходит при **разном** согласовании?

(1) *Серп месяца, **выплывшИЙ** из-за туч.*

Если причастный оборот согласуется **с подлежащим "серп",** то его значимость и самостоятельность еще более усиливается. Все внимание по-прежнему к **форме месяца**. Теперь уже и в добавочном сообщении (***= серп выплыл***) это слово обозначает **субъект** действия.

(2) *Серп месяца, **выплывшЕГО** из-за туч.*

Если причастный оборот согласуется **со словом "месяц"**, то внимание уходит к этому слову, так как теперь оно обозначает **субъект**  действия в причастном обороте (***= месяц выплыл***).

Answer (score 0):

*серп месяца, выплывшИЙ из-за туч/ серп месяца, выплывшЕГО из-за туч?*

Хотелось бы всю фразу, но:

*Над рекой висел серп месяца, выплывшего из-за туч.*
Серп месяца, выплывшего - серп чЕГО? - месяца - месяца какого? - выплывшЕГО. В данном предложении, если это подлежащее, то подлежащим будет "серп месяца".

*Над рекой висел серп месяца, выплывший из-за туч.*
Серп месяца - серп какой? - выплывшИЙ. Оборот с "выплывший..", относится к серп. И "серп" будет скорее всего подлежащим в предложении. Серп - что?(кто?) - он - он какой? - выплывший.

*Так же в ряде случаев возможен и более сложный синтаксис.

*А поднимешь кверху взор свой, а там, высоко, уже и смотритель небесный на посту: серп месяца едва выплывший из-за тучи провожает в далёкое путешествие стаи перелётных птиц, - друзьям путь в непогоду светит.*

Не уверен, правда, в правильности всех знаков препинания, но:

> 3. связанные по смыслу не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым, в состав которого они входят: В марте зерно лежало ссыпанное в закрома (С.‑Щ.) — дело не в том, что зерно лежало, а в том, что оно было ссыпано в закрома... Розенталь.