# Лечу, лечу(,) куда хочу

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая в песне кота Леопольда?

> Лечу, лечу(,) куда хочу.

Comment: Обозначьте проблему и предложите свое решение. Для участника с репутацией 5К это вполне доступно.

Comment: Что с вами случилось, Лео? У вас же были раньше хорошие вопросы. А сейчас новые участники задают более интересные и проблемные темы (2 голоса, три ответа). Это о чем-то говорит. К примеру, в классической литературе часто встречается неоднозначная пунктуация, интересная грамматика, надо только увидеть.  И вы может это сделать лучше, чем многие. Почему бы это не обсудить.  Давайте все же сотрудничать, а не конфликтовать.

Comment: Для сравнения первый вопрос нового участника. Пусть даже и не самый сложный, но он вызвал интерес  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478408/Выплывший-или-выплывшего

Comment: https://nukadeti.ru/pesni/kruchu-pedali - не надо, очевидно.